# Wordpress Algolia plugin, only indexes all posts into searchable_posts index, rather than enabled ones?

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I'm just getting started with Wordpress Algolia - and have gone through the initial documentation.

The problem I'm running into, is I have several post types but only want to have one of them be searchable, and that's a `location` CPT.

1) In the Autocomplete settings, I enable 'location` checkbox and nothing else, hit save.

2) Plugin requests to index that post type, but it ends up indexing / pushing all post type.

Not sure if it's related to how I add CPTs? This is the code I use - i've only pasted one CPT, but they all follow the same structure:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_location',0 );

function register_cpt_location() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Locations', 'location' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Location', 'location' ),
        'add_new'               => _x( 'Add New', 'location' ),
        'add_new_item'          => _x( 'Add New Location', 'location' ),
        'edit_item'             => _x( 'Edit Location', 'location' ),
        'new_item'              => _x( 'New Location', 'location' ),
        'view_item'             => _x( 'View Location', 'location' ),
        'search_items'          => _x( 'Search Locations', 'location' ),
        'not_found'             => _x( 'No locations found', 'location' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => _x( 'No locations found in Trash', 'location' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => _x( 'Parent Location:', 'location' ),
        'menu_name'             => _x( 'Locations', 'location' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'hierarchical'          => true, // True to allow for sub-pages
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-location',
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 4,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'rewrite'               => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'location', $args );
}
```

Any help is appreciated, so I can keep moving forward!

Second question I had - is that is it possible to have multiple search autocomplete / instances, like you have in SearchWP?

For example, a different page to search for a location and another for a service.

Comment: 'exclude_from_search'   => true,

Comment: I didn't think of that, should have. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'hierarchical'          => true, // True to allow for sub-pages
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-location',
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 4,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
```

> 'exclude_from_search'   => false,

```
    'has_archive'           => true,
    'query_var'             => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'rewrite'               => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'post'
);
```

Comment: Mujeebu, do you have any idea if I can have multiple search instances? I need three different "instances", where I can search by a specific post type only. Such as "Search by location", "Search by Provider" etc...